# ANSI C & WinAPI: how to get a handle to the window from hook procedure?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm writing a very simple program, which prints color of selected pixel. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define UNICODE

LRESULT CALLBACK mouse_hook_low_level(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(wParam == WM_MOUSEMOVE) {
        //Need to get a handle to the window!
        InvalidateRect(window, NULL, FALSE); 
        UpdateWindow(window);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK window_process(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC hdc;
    HFONT font;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    int r, g, b;
    POINT p;
    RECT background_rect, color_rect;
    wchar_t buffer[256];

    switch(message) {
        case WM_PAINT:
            GetCursorPos(&p);
            r = GetRValue(GetPixel(dc, p.x, p.y));
            g = GetGValue(GetPixel(dc, p.x, p.y));
            b = GetBValue(GetPixel(dc, p.x, p.y));
            hdc = BeginPaint(window, &ps);
            background_rect.left = 0;
            background_rect.right = 199;
            background_rect.top = 0;
            background_rect.bottom = 99;
            FillRect(hdc, &background_rect, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1));
            font = CreateFont(
                14,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                FW_DONTCARE,
                FALSE,
                FALSE,
                FALSE,
                DEFAULT_CHARSET,
                OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS,
                CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
                CLEARTYPE_QUALITY,
                VARIABLE_PITCH,
                TEXT("Times New Roman")
            );
            SelectObject(hdc, font);
            swprintf_s(buffer, 256, L"Coordinates: (%d, %d)", p.x, p.y);
            TextOut(hdc, 70, 10, buffer, wcslen(buffer));
            swprintf_s(buffer, 256, L"RGB: (%d, %d, %d)", r, g, b);
            TextOut(hdc, 70, 40, buffer,  wcslen(buffer));
            color_rect.left = 10;
            color_rect.right = 60;
            color_rect.top = 10;
            color_rect.bottom = 60;
            FillRect(hdc, &color_rect, (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(r, g, b)));
            EndPaint(window, &ps);
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(window);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            ReleaseDC(window, hdc);
            return DefWindowProc(window, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    ReleaseDC(window, hdc);
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    LPCWSTR class_name = L"name";
    MSG message;
    WNDCLASSEX window_class;
    HWND window;
    HHOOK MouseHook;

    window_class.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = window_process;
    window_class.cbClsExtra = 0;
    window_class.cbWndExtra = 0;
    window_class.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    window_class.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    window_class.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    window_class.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    window_class.lpszClassName = class_name;
    window_class.hInstance = hInstance;
    window_class.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    RegisterClassEx(&window_class);
    window = CreateWindow(
        class_name,
        L"Pixel color",
        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        200,
        100,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );
    ShowWindow(window, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    MouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, mouse_hook_low_level, hInstance, 0);
    while(GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(MouseHook);
    return message.wParam;
}
```

The question is: how can I get a handle to the window for further window update in hook procedure at line 9? And what can you say generally about my code? I'm a student and have a little C-programming experience, could you point out my errors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use `FindWindow` or store your window handle more globally.

Comment: But isn't it a bad practice to use global variables? Anyway, this is helpful answer, thanks.

Comment: They should be avoided when possible. I'm not sure if there's any better storage solution in C, but something like that will be needed if you want the exact window every time. The other possibility is using `FindWindow` with your class name and title, but it's possible, though unlikely, that it could pick up another with the same info or that another app could change your title.

Comment: You can use Global variable, or you can use encapsulation in C (static file scoping). But it's more natural way to use global variable in C in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try [WindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If it fails to find a window, i.e. it's not your process window, then enumerate all top-level windows and all its child windows to find a topmost window under the mouse pointer.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure which one the OP wants, but there's no need to remove yours.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work when mouse is out of my application window range.